# Modal window doesn't close smoothly

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, css-transitions, modal-window

The modal window opens smoothly and there are no problems with this, but when closed, it closes instantly and no animation works. What needs to be fixed/added?

Modal component:

```
const ModalContent = ({ children, closeModal }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const listenerHandler = (e) => {
      if (e.key === 'Escape') {
        closeModal()
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener('keydown', listenerHandler)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', listenerHandler)
    }
  }, [closeModal])

  return children
}

export function Modal({
  showModal, handleClose, children,
}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    showModal
      ? document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
      : document.body.style.overflow = 'unset'
  }, [showModal])

  if (!showModal) return null

  const classes = classNames({
    modal: true,
    hide: !showModal,
  })

  return createPortal(
    <div className={classes} onClick={handleClose}>
      <div className="modalContent" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>

        <ModalContent closeModal={handleClose}>
          {children}
        </ModalContent>

      </div>
    </div>,

    document.getElementById('modal-root'),
  )
}
```

Css style:

```
.modal {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: .4s;
}

.modal.hide {
    animation-name: fade-out;
    animation-duration: .5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
     from {
         opacity: 0.7;
     }
     to {
         opacity: 1;
     }
 }

 @keyframes fade-out {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

The component where the modal window is used:

```
export function Project({
  projectName, projectDescription, projectLinkToGitHub, arrayOfUsedTools, orientation,
}) {
  const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(null)
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)

  const imageClickHandler = (picture) => {
    setCurrentImage(picture)
    setShowModal(true)
  }

  const handleClose = () => setShowModal(false)

  return (
     ......
     <Swiper
        spaceBetween={30}
        centeredSlides
        autoplay={{
        delay: 2000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,}}
        pagination={{
        clickable: true,}}
        navigation
        modules={[Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation]}
        grabCursor
        loop
        slidesPerView={1}
        className={leftStyles.swiperContainer}
        >
         {dogFoodImages.map((picture, i) => (
            <SwiperSlide
              key={i}
              className={leftStyles.swiperSlide}
              onClick={() => imageClickHandler(picture)}
             >
               <img
                  src={picture}
                  alt={picture}
                  className={leftStyles.screens}
               />
             </SwiperSlide>
     ......
      <Modal showModal={showModal} handleClose={handleClose}>
        <img
          src={currentImage}
          alt=""
          className={rightStyles.screensForModal}
        />
      </Modal>
```

The bottom line is, there is a swiper with pictures, when you click on the picture, it is saved in a react state, and a modal window opens with this picture. When opening, the animation works, but when closing, nothing works, it closes instantly.

Tried to use modal window from react-overlay, CSSTransition (React Transition Group), but it didn't work out!

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a state that corresponds to closing the window.

```
const [isClosing, setIsClosing] = useState(false);
```

And add this class to the modal window by condition

```
[cls.isClosing]: isClosing
```

.module.scss

```
 .isClosing {
    .content {
        transform: scale(0.2);
    }
}
```